# Select rows in dataframe unill conditions in multiple column are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value2': [30, 28, 27, 24, 25, 29, 28, 28, 26, 25], 'value3': [29, 29, 27, 25, 24, 27, 27, 26, 26, 26], 'value4': [30, 29, 25, 25, 25, 29, 28, 28, 25, 26]})`

| id | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 29 | 30 |
| 1 | 28 | 29 | 29 |
| 1 | 27 | 27 | 25 |
| 1 | 24 | 25 | 25 |
| 1 | 25 | 24 | 25 |
| 2 | 29 | 27 | 29 |
| 2 | 28 | 27 | 28 |
| 2 | 28 | 26 | 28 |
| 2 | 26 | 26 | 25 |
| 2 | 25 | 26 | 26 |

and I need to select all rows within each `id` untill the conditions are met in columns `value2`, `value3`and `value4`. The condition is as follows: select all rows in each group (`id`) untill the value in any of the columns (`value2`, `value3` or `value4`) less or equals to 25.
So my final table should be like this:

| id | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 29 | 30 |
| 1 | 28 | 29 | 29 |
| 1 | 27 | 27 | 25 |
| 2 | 29 | 27 | 29 |
| 2 | 28 | 27 | 28 |
| 2 | 28 | 26 | 28 |
| 2 | 26 | 26 | 25 |

I have tried `df[df['value2'].eq(25).cummin() | df['value3'].eq(25).cummin() | df['value4'].eq(25).cummin()]` but it is stricktly to 25 and not less or equal to 25, and works only for the whole datafame (not for each `id`). What is the best way to filter the datafame based on my conditions?

Comment: looks like the row `1, 24, 25, 25` should not be there because the previous  row already has a `25` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply) with [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html), [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
m = (
 df.filter(like='value').le(25).any(axis=1)
   .groupby(df['id'], group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: ~g.cummax().shift(fill_value=False))
)

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
   id  value2  value3  value4
0   1      30      29      30
1   1      28      29      29
2   1      27      27      25
5   2      29      27      29
6   2      28      27      28
7   2      28      26      28
8   2      26      26      25
```

Answer (score 1):

equivalent to `value2 > 25 and value3 > 25 and value4 >= 25`, so a very fast boolean mask solution :

```py
df[(df['value2'].gt(25) & df['value3'].gt(25) & df['value4'].ge(25))]
```

```py
   id  value2  value3  value4
0   1      30      29      30
1   1      28      29      29
2   1      27      27      25
5   2      29      27      29
6   2      28      27      28
7   2      28      26      28
8   2      26      26      25
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is shortest way to do it, but based on your various conditions, think this will give you what you need... `df` is your existing dataframe and `df1` will be your filtered dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value2': [30, 28, 27, 24, 25, 29, 28, 28, 26, 25], 'value3': [29, 29, 27, 25, 24, 27, 27, 26, 26, 26], 'value4': [30, 29, 25, 25, 25, 29, 28, 28, 25, 26]})

df1=pd.DataFrame()
for ID in df.id.unique(): ##For each ID
    for _, row in df[df.id==ID].iterrows(): ## For each row
        df1=df1.append(row)  ## First append
        if row.value4 <= 25 or row.value2 <= 25 or row.value3 <= 25:
            break ## Check if 25 or below exists and if yes, exit
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to use `idxmin` , `idxmax` :

```
cols = df.drop('id',axis=1).columns
g = df.assign(t=df[cols].le(25).any(axis=1)).groupby('id')
m = g['t'].idxmax()
f = g['t'].idxmin()
out = pd.concat([df.iloc[s:e+1] for s, e in zip(f.values, m.values)])
print(out)

   id  value2  value3  value4
0   1      30      29      30
1   1      28      29      29
2   1      27      27      25
5   2      29      27      29
6   2      28      27      28
7   2      28      26      28
8   2      26      26      25
```

Answer (score 0):

I will create a temporory column to store value 1 if the value across the row is <= 25. Then I will use cumsum function:

```
df['minval']= np.where(df[['value2','value2','value3']].min(axis=1)<=25,1,0)

df['minval']= df.groupby('id')['minval'].cumsum()

df[df.minval<=1].drop(columns='minval')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `.transform('idxmax')`

```
df.loc[df.index<=df[['value2','value3','value4']].le(25).any(axis=1).groupby(df['id']).transform('idxmax')]
```

Output:

```
   id  value2  value3  value4
0   1      30      29      30
1   1      28      29      29
2   1      27      27      25
5   2      29      27      29
6   2      28      27      28
7   2      28      26      28
8   2      26      26      25
```